# Why the vectoriser's(TF-IDF) intense change the shape of the input if it is given in two different lines?

Tags: nlp, vectorization, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
X_test_tfidf[0].shape
```

> **X_test_tfidf[0].shape = (1, 312)**
>
> But now I want to vectorize another comment (to test it on the model.)

```
singleItemtest = vectorizer.fit_transform([df_selected['Report'][10]]) # it will be random comment but for now lets choose it from dataset to keep it simple.
singleItemtest = vectorizer.transform([df_selected['Report'][10]])
```

> **test.shape = (1, 40)**

Why the shape of report has changed. its the same item from same dataset?